# ingest pipeline not preserving the date type field

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat, opensearch

Here is my JSON data that i am trying to send from filebeat to ingest pipeline "logpipeline.json" in opensearch.

json data

```
{
   "@timestamp":"2022-11-08T10:07:05+00:00",
   "client":"10.x.x.x",
   "server_name":"example.stack.com",
   "server_port":"80",
   "server_protocol":"HTTP/1.1",
   "method":"POST",
   "request":"/example/api/v1/",
   "request_length":"200",
   "status":"500",
   "bytes_sent":"598",
   "body_bytes_sent":"138",
   "referer":"",
   "user_agent":"Java/1.8.0_191",
   "upstream_addr":"10.x.x.x:10376",
   "upstream_status":"500",
   "gzip_ratio":"",
   "content_type":"application/json",
   "request_time":"6.826",
   "upstream_response_time":"6.826",
   "upstream_connect_time":"0.000",
   "upstream_header_time":"6.826",
   "remote_addr":"10.x.x.x",
   "x_forwarded_for":"10.x.x.x",
   "upstream_cache_status":"",
   "ssl_protocol":"TLSv",
   "ssl_cipher":"xxxx",
   "ssl_session_reused":"r",
   "request_body":"{\"date\":null,\"sourceType\":\"BPM\",\"processId\":\"xxxxx\",\"comment\":\"Process status: xxxxx: \",\"user\":\"xxxx\"}",
   "response_body":"{\"statusCode\":500,\"reasonPhrase\":\"Internal Server Error\",\"errorMessage\":\"xxxx\"}",
   "limit_req_status":"",
   "log_body":"1",
   "connection_upgrade":"close",
   "http_upgrade":"",
   "request_uri":"/example/api/v1/",
   "args":""
}
```

Filebeat to Opensearch log shipping

```
# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["192.168.29.117:9200"]
  pipeline: logpipeline
  #index: "filebeatelastic-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  index: "nginx_dev-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  # Protocol - either `http` (default) or `https`.
  protocol: "https"
  ssl.enabled: true
  ssl.verification_mode: none

  # Authentication credentials - either API key or username/password.
  #api_key: "id:api_key"
  username: "filebeat"
  password: "filebeat"
```

I am carrying out the "data" fields transformation in the ingest pipeline for some of the fields by doing type conversion which works perfectly. But the only problem i am facing is with the "@timestamp".

The "@timestamp" is of "date" type and once the json data goes through the pipeline i am mapping the json data message to root level json object called "data". In that transformed data the "data.@timestamp" is showing as type "string" even though i haven't done any transformation for it.

Opensearch ingestpipeline - logpipeline.json

```
{
  "description" : "Logging Pipeline",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "json" : {
        "field" : "message",
        "target_field" : "data"
      }
    },
    {
      "date" : {
        "field" : "data.@timestamp",
    "formats" : ["ISO8601"]
      }
    },
    {
      "convert" : {
        "field" : "data.body_bytes_sent",
        "type": "integer",
        "ignore_missing": true,
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    },
    {
      "convert" : {
        "field" : "data.bytes_sent",
        "type": "integer",
        "ignore_missing": true,
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    },
    {
      "convert" : {
        "field" : "data.request_length",
        "type": "integer",
        "ignore_missing": true,
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    },
    {
      "convert" : {
        "field" : "data.request_time",
        "type": "float",
        "ignore_missing": true,
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    },
    {
      "convert" : {
        "field" : "data.upstream_connect_time",
        "type": "float",
        "ignore_missing": true,
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    },
    {
      "convert" : {
        "field" : "data.upstream_header_time",
        "type": "float",
        "ignore_missing": true,
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    },
    {
      "convert" : {
        "field" : "data.upstream_response_time",
        "type": "float",
        "ignore_missing": true,
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way i can preserve the "@timestamp" "date" type field even after the transformation carried out in ingest pipeline?

indexed document image:

[image]

Edit1: Update ingest pipeline simulate result

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "index_date" : "2022.11.08",
          "@timestamp" : "2022-11-08T12:07:05.000+02:00",
          "message" : """
        { "@timestamp": "2022-11-08T10:07:05+00:00", "client": "10.x.x.x", "server_name": "example.stack.com", "server_port": "80", "server_protocol": "HTTP/1.1", "method": "POST", "request": "/example/api/v1/", "request_length": "200", "status": "500", "bytes_sent": "598", "body_bytes_sent": "138", "referer": "", "user_agent": "Java/1.8.0_191", "upstream_addr": "10.x.x.x:10376", "upstream_status": "500", "gzip_ratio": "", "content_type": "application/json", "request_time": "6.826", "upstream_response_time": "6.826", "upstream_connect_time": "0.000", "upstream_header_time": "6.826", "remote_addr": "10.x.x.x", "x_forwarded_for": "10.x.x.x", "upstream_cache_status": "", "ssl_protocol": "TLSv", "ssl_cipher": "xxxx", "ssl_session_reused": "r", "request_body": "{\"date\":null,\"sourceType\":\"BPM\",\"processId\":\"xxxxx\",\"comment\":\"Process status: xxxxx: \",\"user\":\"xxxx\"}", "response_body": "{\"statusCode\":500,\"reasonPhrase\":\"Internal Server Error\",\"errorMessage\":\"xxxx\"}", "limit_req_status": "", "log_body": "1", "connection_upgrade": "close", "http_upgrade": "", "request_uri": "/example/api/v1/", "args": ""}
        """,
          "data" : {
            "server_name" : "example.stack.com",
            "request" : "/example/api/v1/",
            "referer" : "",
            "log_body" : "1",
            "upstream_addr" : "10.x.x.x:10376",
            "body_bytes_sent" : 138,
            "upstream_header_time" : 6.826,
            "ssl_cipher" : "xxxx",
            "response_body" : """{"statusCode":500,"reasonPhrase":"Internal Server Error","errorMessage":"xxxx"}""",
            "upstream_status" : "500",
            "request_time" : 6.826,
            "upstream_cache_status" : "",
            "content_type" : "application/json",
            "client" : "10.x.x.x",
            "user_agent" : "Java/1.8.0_191",
            "ssl_protocol" : "TLSv",
            "limit_req_status" : "",
            "remote_addr" : "10.x.x.x",
            "method" : "POST",
            "gzip_ratio" : "",
            "http_upgrade" : "",
            "bytes_sent" : 598,
            "request_uri" : "/example/api/v1/",
            "x_forwarded_for" : "10.x.x.x",
            "args" : "",
            "@timestamp" : "2022-11-08T10:07:05+00:00",
            "upstream_connect_time" : 0.0,
            "request_body" : """{"date":null,"sourceType":"BPM","processId":"xxxxx","comment":"Process status: xxxxx: ","user":"xxxx"}""",
            "request_length" : 200,
            "ssl_session_reused" : "r",
            "server_port" : "80",
            "upstream_response_time" : 6.826,
            "connection_upgrade" : "close",
            "server_protocol" : "HTTP/1.1",
            "status" : "500"
          }
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2023-01-18T08:06:35.335066236Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you run what you see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/consulthys/7279e7a47b9a9d32cc5406edde48f75c) and update your question with the result you get?

Comment: hi @Val, updated the simulate results in my question edits

Comment: Weird, because when I'm trying, the top level `@timestamp` field indicates the same as the one in the `data` section: `"@timestamp" : "2022-11-08T10:07:05.000Z",` which means it's being parsed correctly

Comment: You can use *convert* processor to update the field type during ingestion.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/convert-processor.html

Comment: @Val, may i know what is the type you see for timestamp and "data.timestamp" fields. I wanted to have both of them to be of "date" type which is my problem currently

Comment: @MusabDogan, i already had a look at it but the convert processor do not support date format. "The supported types include: integer, long, float, double, string, boolean, ip, and auto.". I want to preserver the timestamp field type which is "date" even after the ingest pipeline processing which is not happening

Comment: @sb9 The easiest way to solve this problem will be to set `data.@timestamp` as a date in **index_template** before creating the index.
https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/index-templates/

Comment: I did not create the index/mapping first, I just indexed a new document with the `logpipeline` and the created index mapping looks like this `"@timestamp" : { "type" : "date" }, "data" : { "properties" : { "@timestamp" : { "type" : "date" }`. So everything went according to the plan, on ES 7.17

Comment: thanks @Val, will have look further if its something to do with the opensearch that i am using or templates/mappings that is getting loaded from filebeat to opensearch..

Comment: You should make sure to start your testing on a fresh index, because if the index already exists and the type is already `text` it's not going to change

Comment: @Val, so i created the pipeline and tried to ingest a single document directly from the kibana dev portal and that worked. i can see timestamp and data.timestamp with date type format. But if i send the doc from filebeat to elasticsearch through pipeline for indexing it does not work

Comment: @MusabDogan - i can try to update the index template. But i am sending the logs from filebeat to elasticsearch and dont want to manually do templating thing. Seems filebeat is sending a some default template due to which this might be a problem.

Comment: What is your version of Filebeat and Opensearch?

Comment: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat-oss:7.12.1 and opensearchproject/opensearch:2.3.0 - i am using the docker-compose file for the services

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to resolve my issue. I updated the filebeat.yml with the following. Previously template name and pattern was different. But this default template name "filebeat" and pattern "filebeat" seems to be doing the job for me.

To

```
setup.template.name: "filebeat"
setup.template.pattern: "filebeat"

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
  #index.codec: best_compression
  #_source.enabled: false
```

But still need to figure our how templates work though